# Browser url getting changed showing actual URL location

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi Bellow is my Rewrite rule,Its working perfectly,

```
  RewriteRule ^forms/result/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    http://www.xyz.com/forms/search_box.php?query=$1&page=$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

when am requesting bellow link in brouser URL

```
 http://www.xyz.com/forms/result/700011/1
```

its opening specific search_box.php file with proper data,but brouser URL changed to actual url just like bellow.I don't want to change the requesting url(`http://www.xyz.com/forms/result/700011/1`) on browser.

```
http://www.xyz.com/forms/search_box.php?query=700019&page=3
```

Comment: you haven't written the rule for `form/search_box.php` ?

Comment: am mapping ^forms/result/ to forms/search_box.php

Comment: post the whole rewrite block

Comment: hi @Tabby I have only this RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^forms/result/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    http://www.xyz.com/forms/search_box.php?query=$1&page=$2 [R=301,NC,L]`